Google Sheets - Sum multiple columns with conditions on columns and rows
I have the following table



A
B
C
D
E
F




product_type
adoption
adoption
other
retail
retail


january
10
15
50
12
20


january
15
115
56
1
10


february
20
100
50
0
100



I want a formula to sum all the values in columns B, C, D, E, F where the product_type (line 2) is equal to "adoption" and the month (column A) is equal to "january".
So that would be 10 + 15 + 15 + 115 = 155
I tried different things like SUMIFS(B3:F, A3:A, "january", B2:2, "adoption") but I get the error Array Arguments to SUMIFS are of different size"

You can use the following formula:
=SUMPRODUCT(B3:F*(B2:F2="adoption")*(A3:A="january"))

Or
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(A3:A&B2:F2,"januaryadoption",B3:F)) 

